# Using Logitech mouse & keyboard on TESmart KVM switch with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, usb-device

I would like to use a wireless logitech ERGO K860 keyboard and a wireless MX vertical mouse with my laptop (running ubuntu 20.04).

### What works:

**Windows:**

Both devices work with windows machines with and without using the KVM swith

**Ubuntu:**

Both devices also work with ubunto 20.04, when I plug in the usb-receivers to the laptop's usb interfaces directly. This is the dmesg output upon doing so with the keyboard's dongle:

````
[  416.600180] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  416.751050] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b, bcdDevice=24.11
[  416.751053] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  416.751054] usb 2-1: Product: USB Receiver
[  416.751056] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  416.761116] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0019: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2
[  416.894339] input: Logitech ERGO K860 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0019/0003:046D:4088.001A/input/input38
[  416.894624] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4088.001A: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech ERGO K860] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2:1```
````

lsusb gives me

```
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

#### What doesn't work:

When instead I plug keyboard and mouse to my TESmart 4x1 HDMI KVM Switch connected to the laptop both devices do not work and the dmseg ouput is (again keyboard only):

```
[  703.539962] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 16
[  703.889856] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[  704.117331] usb 2-1.3: language id specifier not provided by device, defaulting to English
[  704.126963] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b, bcdDevice=24.11
[  704.126969] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  704.142659] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0023: hiddev1,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [HID 046d:c52b] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3/input2
```

lsusb still gives me

```
Bus 002 Device 015: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

#### What instead works:

I own a Jelly Comb wireless keyboard & mouse combo, that upon plugin of the accompanying receiver to the switch work without any problem.

Here is dmesg's output:

```
[ 1113.139530] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 18
[ 1113.491369] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[ 1113.721492] usb 2-1.3: language id specifier not provided by device, defaulting to English
[ 1113.738389] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=248a, idProduct=8367, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1113.738394] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1113.745953] input: HID 248a:8367 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/0003:248A:8367.0027/input/input39
[ 1113.746136] input: HID 248a:8367 Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/0003:248A:8367.0027/input/input40
[ 1113.803602] input: HID 248a:8367 System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/0003:248A:8367.0027/input/input41
[ 1113.803803] hid-generic 0003:248A:8367.0027: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [HID 248a:8367] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3/input0
[ 1113.805415] input: HID 248a:8367 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.1/0003:248A:8367.0028/input/input42
[ 1113.863886] hid-generic 0003:248A:8367.0028: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [HID 248a:8367] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3/input1
```

lsusb gives me:

```
Bus 002 Device 020: ID 248a:8367 Maxxter 
Bus 002 Device 015: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
```

It still shows the (unplugged) logitech keyboard, but I am unsure what to make of this...

Naively - and possibly wrongly - I'd conclude that the correct driver is  loaded also when connecting the logitech keyboard to the switch but the device is not recognized, whereas the Jelly Comb does the trick with a generic driver...

I read this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/601078/linux-cant-use-usb-devices-attached-to-a-kvm-switch) on a seamingly related issue but have to confess it didn't help me.

**Additional info:**
I see the same thing on my Raspi 4 (Raspbian buster)

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: I finally got this working using this solution : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246895/mouse-and-keyboard-over-kvm-switch-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20

Comment: This solution worked for me :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246895/mouse-and-keyboard-over-kvm-switch-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20

Comment: Nice! Also works with 22.04. - Thanks for pointing this out!